# how to increase time of NotificationCompat showing

Tags: android, notifications

I am using NotificationCompat to show incoming call but issue is that the time limit is less, I want to show NotificationCompat for 40seconds, is there any way to increase time for showing notification, because the current time for showing notification is less than 40 seconds

```
    Intent dismissIntent = new Intent();
    PendingIntent piDismiss = PendingIntent.getService(ctx, 0,dismissIntent, 0);
    Intent callIntent = new Intent();
    PendingIntent pendingcall = PendingIntent.getService(ctx, 0, callIntent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Ping Notification").setContentText("Tomorrow will be your birthday.")
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL).setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .addAction(R.drawable.call_end, "Dismiss", piDismiss)
            .addAction(R.drawable.call_accept, "Accept", pendingcall);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heads-up notifications visibility length is set in the OS and cannot be changed